# visualize boxes in tensorflow object detection

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
  image = Image.open(image_path)
  # the array based representation of the image will be used later in order to prepare the
  # result image with boxes and labels on it.
  image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)
  # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
  image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
  # Actual detection.
  output_dict = run_inference_for_single_image(image_np, detection_graph)
  # Visualization of the results of a detection.
  vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
      image_np,
      output_dict['detection_boxes'],
      output_dict['detection_classes'],
      output_dict['detection_scores'],
      category_index,
      instance_masks=output_dict.get('detection_masks'),
      use_normalized_coordinates=True,
      line_thickness=8)
  plt.figure(figsize=IMAGE_SIZE)
  plt.imshow(image_np)
```

In one of the codes for tensorflow object detection API, there is the vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array method which draws bounding boxes on the image and returns the new image_np which is fed into plt.imshow(image_np) to display. However, **vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array method is not assigned to image_np variable** as shown in the code. How does plt.imshow(image_np) get the latest(The image which has the drawn bounding box) image?

Comment: But should it be image_np = vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array( ........... ), then the function can return the new modified content?

Comment: No. You are passing an array. The *contents* in the array (the image pixels) are modified.

Comment: Okay thank you very much. I am new to python lol

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the image_np value into `visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array` as the first parameter and the function modifies its contents to draw the bounding boxes. The code is open source. You can check it out for yourself [here.](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py)